# Merge range into single column for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a "start" and "end" column that I would like to be used for merging a range from another table. I would like to concatenate the "descriptions" together of the range. Is this possible?

Below is what my schema looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE verses 
(
  `id` int auto_increment primary key,
  `chapter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `verse` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text
);

CREATE TABLE verses_range 
(
  `id` int auto_increment primary key,
  `chapter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `end` int(11)
);
```

So far, this is what I have but I cannot figure out how to merge the description column of the range. It only gives the description for the first record:

```
SELECT verses_range.*, verses.description
FROM verses_range
INNER JOIN verses
  ON verses_range.start = verses.verse
    AND verses_range.chapter = verses.chapter
```

I have this in SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0578e/1) and returns this:

```
ID  CHAPTER START   END DESCRIPTION
1   2   156 162 Donec tincidunt fringilla libero et vestibulum.
2   3   53  (null)  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

However, I am trying to get the description value for the first record to be:

> Donec tincidunt fringilla libero et vestibulum. (156) Donec auctor a
>   velit eu tempor. (157) Etiam sed lobortis sapien. (158) Integer ut dui
>   ultricies arcu congue pulvinar. (159) Proin feugiat dignissim rutrum.
>   (160) Mauris eu ultrices ligula. (161) Ut varius id enim tempor porta.
>   (162)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this...

```
SELECT verses_range.*, Group_Concat(verses.description)
FROM verses_range
INNER JOIN verses on
    verses_range.chapter = verses.chapter
where start<=verse and verse<=if(isnull(end),start,end)
group by  id,chapter,start,end
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/499186/28)

Comment: But this isn't obeying the range tho. It is concatenating anything with the chapter ID: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/499186/1

Comment: @TruMan1 can you explain range a bit more

Comment: The "verses_range" table has "start" and "end" columns. I only want to grab the verses from the "verses" table that falls between that range. For the example, only verses 156-162.

Answer (score 0):

So, we get something like this...

```
SELECT *
  FROM verses_range r
  JOIN verses v
    ON v.verse BETWEEN r.start AND r.END;

| ID | CHAPTER | START | END | VERSE |                                     DESCRIPTION |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |       2 |   156 | 162 |   156 | Donec tincidunt fringilla libero et vestibulum. |
|  1 |       2 |   156 | 162 |   157 |                 Donec auctor a velit eu tempor. |
|  1 |       2 |   156 | 162 |   158 |                      Etiam sed lobortis sapien. |
|  1 |       2 |   156 | 162 |   159 |  Integer ut dui ultricies arcu congue pulvinar. |
|  1 |       2 |   156 | 162 |   160 |                 Proin feugiat dignissim rutrum. |
|  1 |       2 |   156 | 162 |   161 |                      Mauris eu ultrices ligula. |
|  1 |       2 |   156 | 162 |   162 |                 Ut varius id enim tempor porta. |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0578e/1

Now what?